How to bind cells positions
I have a Filter function that shows data from another table, filters out what I need and I've put conveniently comments in the side cell.
Once the data is changed the data shown from the filter changes also and switches positions etc. and messes up the comments. The comments do not change it's position.
How can I make it so that the comment cell are fixed with the filtered data, that they can change position and also disappear if the filtered data also disappears.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why not use Autofilter on the original table?

This is how Excel works. The filter function returns a range. If you put comment text next to that range, the comments are not related or connected to the results of the filter formula. The problem is the architecture, not Excel.
Consider adding a comment column to the original table. Then you can filter the table in place and the comments stay in their proper positions.

Unfortunately the original table is too much that putting comment on them is a bit inconvenient. That's why I've filtered what I need to check and put comments on it and at the end of the workday I change the original data and some data that were filtered stops showing up (as intented) and the comments stay in place.
Is there any other suggestion to this?

As I said, it's how Excel works. You won't be able to combine a Filter() formula with manually enterd data. You may want to review your data structure or your work process.
